# How to use the local file in curl instead of remote file URL in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

Can someone help me here, I have the command as below, But instead of downloading the file from remote every time I wanted to save to local and access ,How I can achieve this

> `sudo ./perform.sh https://someurl/util.zip serverhost:9998 serverhost2`

But I have downloaded the file in data folder and trying to execute the command as but its not working , Can you please help me

> `sudo ./perform.sh 'util.zip' serverhost:9998 serverhost2`

Comment: You can start a local server in the folder, then use `http://localhost/util.zip`

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh I wanted to use from the local path instead of setting local server , Is there any way

Comment: Then modify your shell script to use curl only if file doesn't exist already

Answer (score -1):

use file:///path/to/file/test.tar.gz